# Accounting of filesystem accesses

Tags: linux, filesystems, monitoring

Is there any way to keep track of number of times each file system is accessed through system calls? I know that the super block will contain the details about the file system. But how can we access the superblock?

Comment: There are several layers of abstraction between the user doing a file operation and that data actually touching the disk.  You'll need to be more specific about what exactly it is that you want to keep track of and what filesystems are being used.

Comment: If a file is being opened , how do we find out which file system the file belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at dtrace4linux and sysdig